# How to push a view controller programmatically from Detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

My app has a split view controller as root with master detail view. I'm doing this programmatically without using storyboards. I want to push a new view controller from a button in detail view and close the split view. When I tried, it opened inside the detail view. `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainView, animated: true)`

But I want it to open full screen and have a back button to goto the split view.  How can I do that?

Comment: So basically you have a SplitViewController presenting the master (as a side bar) and a detail view (as the larger part).
You want to tap a button in the detail view and it will push a new view controller into the view stack of the detail view and also make the master (side bar) disappear until back is tapped. correct?

Comment: @MarkosDarkin yes, it's one way of doing it. Do you know how can I achieve that?
And also I'm wondering can't we push the new view controller for the entire split controller? I mean without pushing it to Detail view controller and hiding master? So that I can see the previous detail view when back is tapped.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need either present it Modally or change the rootViewController in corresponding to your action.

Comment: Presenting modally is not going to work in my situation. How can I change the rootViewController from detail view ?

Comment: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = [YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER]